# How pass object to new activity if object not implemet Serializable or Parceble?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want pass my object to new Activity by intent. But I can not change my objet and implement it from Serializable or Parceble. How can i pass this object whith another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JSON for this purpose.
First of all you have to create a POJO class and then do the following in your FirstActivity. Object is your POJO class.

```
Object obj = new Object();
String toJson = new Gson().toJson(obj);
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("json", toJson);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now do the following in your SecondActivity.

```
String stringExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("json");
Object fromJson = new Gson().fromJson(stringExtra, Object.class);
```

Now you can access your setters and getters of your POJO class using "fromJson".

Answer (score 0):

The easiest option would be [gson](https://github.com/google/gson)!

Although I should mention that gson is a bit slower than either Parcelable or Seralizable. If your classes are simple enough, then it might be worth wrapping them in your own parcelable class.

Comment: Up vote it just because: 1º Its a possible solution, 2º someone just down vote it without reasoning like usually in SO,

Answer (score 0):

Can you recreate it **manually**? I.e. call its constructor and its setters. If yes, you should either create a Parcelable as wrapper for the object.

Answer (score 0):

You could also write a POJO representing the data required for rebuilding the object on the activity and make that class Parceble or Serializable then pass that pojo and make a method that build an object of your type from the pojo

Answer (score 0):

Without using parceble or serializable you cannot pass java objects. Thats it. You can make an instance of hash map and store values in a key-value pair and then put it in a bundle and pass it in an intent to another activity, but this is **NOT** the modular way to do it.